# Remember Cell Order Swift with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a UITableView on my screen, and I have the capability to rearrange the order, using the default `canMoveRowAt` method and setting it as true.

Now, I would like to somehow save the order, using Firebase, since I am pulling the children and cell data from there, too.

When I rearrange the order of the UITableView cells, how do I make sure this is in effect with Firebase Realtime Database?

Below is a snapshot of the structure of my DB.
[image]

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer without knowing anything about your model. If, for example, your data is just stored as an array in Realtime Database, just save your newly-reordered array back to the database. If you are using items with unique keys that are *not* in an array, you'd need to store some order data along with them.

Comment: @jnpdx, I have added the model. What do you think now? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you already have a listOrder field. Are you using it?

Comment: @jnpdx, I am not. I put that in as a random place holder, thinking I will need it

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question in this case. Do you just want to know if you *should* use that field. Or do you not know *how* to?

Comment: @jnpdx, i don’t know how to. I don’t know what to do on the code that orders all of the values.

Comment: You haven't shown any of your code, so I'm not sure how useful of an answer you'll get here without it. It sounds like once your table is re-ordered, you'd need to map that new order into your `listOrder` fields and then write to the database.

Comment: You only need to cross check this listOrder value is as per your arrange order or not

Comment: Cutting to the chase; the order of your data needs to be stored in Firebase. Using the listOrder property is perfectly fine, it should be from 0 to x. As the user changes the order in the UI, your dataSource which backs the tableView should be updated as well. e.g. user moved row 0 to row 1, then the datasource will have those elements updated as well. Then the tricky bit; if row 0 is moved to row 7, then all of the rows between need to have their position updated as well. row 1 becomes row 0, row 2 becomes row 1 etc. So you're need to account for that by updating Firebase as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `key` and `listOrder`, once you sort your data on the device, update your `dataSource` models listOrder field with the index that it is now at. After that, update your Firebase data for each item in your updated `dataSource` model that has changes since you have a unique key and all you have to do is just send the new `listOrder` for that items key. Again like mentioned in comments its hard to help you without your code, but the high level solution is to update the list order using a unique key that you have for each item